# SFINAE and std::enable_if in dummy template parameters to select struct based on two criteria

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

Lets say we want a templated struct `part` to be called by `part<U,D>`, where `D` is of type `U`:

```
template<typename U, U D>
struct part{};
```

We what two cases:

1. `U` is an `unsigned` type , and `D%(sizeof(U)*8)==0`
2. `U` is an `unsigned` type , and `D%(sizeof(U)*8)!=0`

Ok to distinguish cases lets have two members: `value` and `divisible`. Base case is no condition is met, and struct is instantiated with `value` and `divisible` both being `false`. If conditions 1) are met I should have `value=true, divisible= false` and if conditions 2) are met I should have `value=true, divisible= true`. Looking ahead lets also say that if 1) or 2) are met, I also have a `type` in the struct.

I set up an auxiliary struct `choice` to use in `std::enable_if` and select the appropriate case through a dummy template argument. The code follows:

```
// to be used in dummy template arguments
template<size_t D>
struct choice{};

// Base case
template<typename U, U D, typename E1 = choice<0>, typename E2 = choice<0> >
struct part{
  static constexpr bool value     = false;
  static constexpr bool divisible = false;
};

// Specialisation 1  <U, D, choice<1>, choice<0> >
template<typename U, U D>
struct part<U,D,std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, choice<1> >, std::enable_if_t<!(D%(sizeof(U)*8)), choice<0> > >{
  static constexpr bool value     = true;
  static constexpr bool divisible = false;
  typedef U type;
};

// Specialisation 2  <U, D, choice<1>, choice<1> >
template<typename U, U D>
struct part<U,D,std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, choice<1> >, std::enable_if_t<(D%(sizeof(U)*8)), choice<1> > >{
  static constexpr bool value     = true;
  static constexpr bool divisible = true;
  typedef U type;
};
```

This compiles. Great. Lets cheack what we did with a simple printing:

```
  std::cout << "Should get 0,0 "<< std::endl;
  std::cout << part<int,5>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << part<int,5>::divisible << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Should get 1,0 "<< std::endl;
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,5>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,5>::divisible << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Should get 1,1 "<< std::endl;    
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,16>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,16>::divisible << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Should get 1,0 "<< std::endl;    
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,30>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,30>::divisible << std::endl;  

  std::cout << "Should get 1,1 "<< std::endl;      
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,32>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << part<uint16_t,32>::divisible << std::endl;


// RESULTS ON TERMINAL ARE:
//
// Should get 0,0 
// 0
// 0
// Should get 1,0 
// 0
// 0
// Should get 1,1 
// 0
// 0
// Should get 1,0 
// 0
// 0
// Should get 1,1 
// 0
// 0
```

So not what I want at all. Ok lets try:

```
std::cout << std::is_same<part<uint16_t,5>::type, uint16_t> << std::endl;

// COMPILATION ERROR:
src/tests/test1.cpp(55): error: class "part<uint16_t={unsigned short}, (uint16_t={unsigned short})5U, choice<0UL>, choice<0UL>>" has no member "type"
    std::cout << std::is_same<part<uint16_t,5>::type, uint16_t> << std::endl;
```

Where am I going wrong? The code compiles so SFINAE is resolving the specialisations. But it seams it always select the base case. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how the SFINAE trick works. You need to give `std::enable_if_t` the same type as second argument as you defined as default argument, so that if the `std::enable_it_t` does not cause substitution failure, the partial specialization matches with a template specialization that does not explicitly specify the defaulted parameter.

Therefore you want to use `choice<0>` everywhere instead of `choice<1>` and because you use it everywhere, you can really use `void` instead of `choice<...>` everywhere and with `void` you can also drop the second argument to `std::enable_if_t` because it is defaulted to that.

Then finally, you don't need two enabler parameters, just connect the conditions with logical operations:

```
// Base case
template<typename U, U D, typename = void>
struct part{
  static constexpr bool value     = false;
  static constexpr bool divisible = false;
};

// Specialisation 1  <U, D>
template<typename U, U D>
struct part<U,D,std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<U> && !(D%(sizeof(U)*8))>{
  static constexpr bool value     = true;
  static constexpr bool divisible = false;
  typedef U type;
};

// Specialisation 2
template<typename U, U D>
struct part<U,D,std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<U> && (D%(sizeof(U)*8))>{
  static constexpr bool value     = true;
  static constexpr bool divisible = true;
  typedef U type;
};
```

Also note that (based on what you showed) you don't need the last specialization:

```
// Base case
template<typename U, U D, typename = void>
struct part{
  static constexpr bool value     = false;
  static constexpr bool divisible = false;
};

// Specialisation 1  <U, D>
template<typename U, U D>
struct part<U,D,std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<U>> {
  static constexpr bool value     = true;
  static constexpr bool divisible = (D%(sizeof(U)*8) == 0);
  typedef U type;
};
```

The SFINAE approach is only necessary for `std::is_unsigned_v` because the expression `(D%(sizeof(U)*8) == 0)` might be ill-formed if `D` has a type which is not an unsigned integer.

Also, since C++17 you can do:

```
template<typename U, U D>
struct part{
  static constexpr bool value     = std::is_unsigned_v<U>;
  static constexpr bool divisible = []{
      if constexpr(value)
          return D%(sizeof(U)*8) == 0;
      else
          return false;
  }();
};
```

to avoid partial specialization completely, even if `U` might be a type for which `D%(sizeof(U)*8)` is ill-formed.

If you do not intend to support types for which `D%(sizeof(U)*8)` is ill-formed, then just use:

```
template<typename U, U D>
struct part{
  static constexpr bool value     = std::is_unsigned_v<U>;
  static constexpr bool divisible = value && (D%(sizeof(U)*8) == 0);
};
```

Comment: Yup that works! Just so I can understand, and hopefully not repeat and propagate my stupid mistakes, if I don't use the default `void` in the specialisation `enable_if`, what is happening exactly?

Comment: @Pana `enable_if_t` will cause substitution failure if the condition is not satisfied, so that the partial specialization will not be viable and otherwise it will just evaluate to the type given as its second argument (`void` by default), so that the partial specialization will specialize for the case where the `E` parameter is that second argument.

Comment: Ok yes, I think I need to understand better the template parameter default value behaviour. Also you are absolutely right on the last code, that is simpler. Many thanks.